# Serialize Integer collection to byte array and deserialize it back

Tags: java, arrays, serialization

I need to have serialization and deserialization of `Collection<Integer>` for storing it in Redis which requires `byte[]`. I've found a code using `ByteBuffer` and `IntBuffer` for serialization:

```
byte[] serializeIntegerCollection(Collection<Integer> collection) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(collection.size() * 4);
    IntBuffer intBuffer = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
    collection.forEach(intBuffer::put);
    return byteBuffer.array();
}
```

And now the code I try to use for deserialization:

```
Collection<Integer> deserializeIntegerCollection(byte[] bytes) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
    IntBuffer intBuffer = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
    return asList(intBuffer.array());
}
```

But `intBuffer.array()` throws `UnsupportedOperationException`. What's wrong with it and how to handle the issue?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Answer (score -1):

you can serialize it like.**serializeIntegerCollection class** must implements **serializable**.

---

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
oos.writeObject(list);
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

you can deserialize it like.**deserializeIntegerCollectionclass**

`ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Collection<Integer> collection= (Collection<Integer>) ois.readObject();`